# Firebase on flutter: Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:generateDebugRFile'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle

I always get the following error message when I try to run my flutter app:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_core:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-common:.
     Required by:
         project :firebase_core
```

This is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:travel_games/loading_screen.dart';
import 'tg_theme.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  // Set default `_initialized` and `_error` state to false
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = false;
  var msg;

  // Define an async function to initialize FlutterFire
  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      // Wait for Firebase to initialize and set `_initialized` state to true
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    } catch(e) {
      // Set `_error` state to true if Firebase initialization fails
      setState(() {
        _error = true;
        msg = e;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Show error message if initialization failed
    if(_error) {
      print('error');
      print(msg);
      return MaterialApp(home: LoadingScreen());
    }

    // Show a loader until FlutterFire is initialized
    if (!_initialized) {
      print('wait');
      return MaterialApp(home: LoadingScreen());
    }

    return MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  //Future<UserCredential> userCredential = FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // waitForAuth();
  }

  void waitForAuth() async {
    //UserCredential user = await userCredential;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: TgAppBar('Reisespiele'),
      body: Container(
        color: TgTheme.getHeaderBackgroundColor(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My dependencies on pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.4.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2
```

I followed the guide on https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview, but it does not work.
It looks like there is something in the .gradle missing, but I could not figure it out :(
Has somebody an idea where my mistake is?

Comment: Did you download google-service.plist or json file from firebase

Comment: Yes, the google-service.json is in the android/app folder